# Wacom Signature Pad STU-530 sólo funciona en Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Tengo una aplicación web en C# , en uno de los apartados tengo la opción de capturar firma desde el dispositivo WACOM y en Internet Explorer funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo ejecuto en Chrome o en Edge no se activa el dispositivo, tan sólo me deja firmar en la pantalla con el ratón.

Perdón por la pésima redacción, pero me estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación y me he encontrado con este problema.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Con la información que proporcionas es dificil que nadie pueda ayudarte, deberías proporcionar más información sobre que tecnología usas en tu app (no sera activex no??), y describir cual es el problema cuando lo ejecutas desde los otros navegadores (_no funciona_  no es muy descriptivo). Un saludo y bienvenido de nuevo.

Comment: No te preocupes por la redacción :) Yo sospecho que el problema es que una aplicación web no tiene permiso en ningun caso para acceder al hardware conectado a un dispositivo. Y como dices que en IE si funciona, sospecho que estas utilizando algun control ActiveX que sí permitía acceso al hardware. Puedes especificar que librería de acceso al WACOM estás usando?

Comment: Creo que efectivamente, el problema va  a ser ese. He encontrado que está utilizado Florentis.DynamicCapture

Comment: Es lo que me temía. ActiveX es una tecnología insegura que ya ni microsoft permite en Edge. Y, por seguridad, los navegadores no permiten que las aplicaciones web accedan al hardware del cliente, asi que el problema no tiene solución fácil que yo conozca. Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30241692) a ver si te sirve...

Comment: He encontrado una extensión para Chrome, se llama IE Tab y simula Internet Explorer. En principio me funciona bien.

Comment: Soy nuevo usando wacom, podrías pasarme de favor el sdk, es gratuito ? necesita licencia ? TNX